# Flutter "Execution failed for task ':app:checkDevelopmentDebugDuplicateClasses'." Build time error

Tags: android, flutter

I just updated the kotlin version in android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.21' // originally ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
```

and after doing this I tried to run my flutter project and it failed with this exception
`

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDevelopmentDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0-Beta (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0-Beta) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.31 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.31)
     Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0-Beta (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0-Beta) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.31 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.31)
     Duplicate class kotlin.random.jdk8.PlatformThreadLocalRandom found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0-Beta (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0-Beta) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.31 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.31)
     Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0-Beta (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0-Beta) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.31 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.31)
     Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$1 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0-Beta (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0-Beta) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.31 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.31)
     Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$2 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0-Beta (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0-Beta) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.31 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.31)
     Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$3 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0-Beta (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0-Beta) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.31 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.31)
     Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$4 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0-Beta (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0-Beta) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.31 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.31)
     Duplicate class kotlin.text.jdk8.RegexExtensionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0-Beta (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0-Beta) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.31 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.31)
     Duplicate class kotlin.time.jdk8.DurationConversionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0-Beta (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0-Beta) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.31 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.31)

     Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 53s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDevelopmentDebug failed with exit code 1
```

**Things I have tried**

I tried flutter clean and running pub get; and then running the project again. The same exception occurred.

I have tried deleting the .gradle folder inside the android folder after doing the above process.

I have also created a new project to check if something is wrong with my installed libraries (Android sdk, flutter sdk etc.) it ran without any error so there is no problem there.

Can someone please help.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/75322799/9585130

Answer (score 2):

Change kotlin version

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.0-Beta'
```