# React Native: Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'

Tags: react-native

I am getting the next error appearing on running `npx react-native run-android`. It came out of nowhere  - no changes have been committed.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable

Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)

Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
     
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
     
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)
     
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)
```

What I tried:

1. **Follow again the installation steps on official react native documentation page: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup**

   ```
    brew install node
    brew install watchman
    brew tap homebrew/cask-versions
    brew install --cask zulu11
   ```
2. **Uninstall and install `Android Studio`**
3. Set `kotlinVersion = "1.8.0"` in **android/build.gradle**:

   ```
    buildToolsVersion = "32.0.0"
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 33
    targetSdkVersion = 33
    // here
    kotlinVersion = "1.8.0"
   ```

It looks like if I get rid of `"react-native-inappbrowser-reborn": "^3.7.0"` library the error is gone and the app launches successfully. But what if I need `react-native-inappbrowser-reborn` in my project?

Thank you mates in advance!

Comment: I'm glad I saw this because I thought I was going crazy! It was working fine yesterday, and now with *no changes to my code,* I also get this very similar error!

Comment: Oh, happy not to be alone here! Will post solution as I find it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execution failed for task ':app:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75248979/execution-failed-for-task-appcheckreleaseduplicateclasses)

Comment: Thank you for response but it didn't work for me :(

Comment: @spatak Are you using `react-native-onesignal`? When I remove it, it compiles. I tried upgrading it but it still fails... researching...

Comment: Hey mate. Yes, I am using `react-native-onesignal`. Actually I was not using `react-native-inappbrowser-reborn` so I was free to remove it. But One Signal is vital for my project

Comment: Yeah same here.. I did not make any code updates. All of a sudden started seeing this error. Strangely I have no idea where that kotlin dependency is coming from. My project uses Java...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is caused by the Kotlin plugin update. You can fix it easily by using configure below:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"

    // Add this line here
    implementation platform('org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0')

    //...omit some code
}
```

You can refer this one: [Kotlin Document](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle-configure-project.html#dependency-on-the-standard-library)

Comment: //  android/app/build.gradle

Comment: Thank you so much, i was lost for quite some time

Answer (score 1):

Add this to android/app/build.gradle

```
configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy {
    eachDependency {
        if ((requested.group == "org.jetbrains.kotlin") && (requested.name.startsWith("kotlin-stdlib"))) {
            useVersion("1.6.10")
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why did you copy-paste the solution from the user above?

Comment: I'm the first one who write the solution, check the time please before judging people

Comment: Checked, yesterday. You were 2 minutes late

Comment: That's for me: 20:44:59
That's for Eli: 20:46:39

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was a combination of the `react-native-iap` and the `react-native-onesignal` packages that was causing the issue.

Upgrading `react-native-onesignal` didn't work, so I upgraded `react-native-iap` as far as I could go without breaking changes, and for me, that was `v7.5.6`.

After upgrading `iap` to `7.5.6`, I also had to add this to my `../android/app/build.gradle` file for it to compile:

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    missingDimensionStrategy 'store', 'play'
}
```

Edit: I think what's happening is that one of your packages has a loose dependency, which caused an unexpected update. So each case could be different.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this for @shopify/flash-list. There is a github issue [1] for it.

To fix it, add `kotlinVersion = "1.8.10"` on your build.gradle file

```json
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
        kotlinVersion = "1.8.10" //  this to be added
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath ("com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15")
    }
}
```

References

1: https://github.com/Shopify/flash-list/issues/862

Answer (score 0):

This fixed my issue

android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
        kotlinVersion = "1.7.22" // add this
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your `android/app/build.gradle` file set kotlin-stdlib to use the same verion

for example:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachDependency {
            if ((requested.group == "org.jetbrains.kotlin") && (requested.name.startsWith("kotlin-stdlib"))) {
                useVersion("1.7.20")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it is not an elegant solution. This error occurred instantly - not due to any code changes or something like this. I think there is something wrong with kotlin or jdk - probably need to update them etc